# How to perform Appium android scroll

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

http://www.dropmocks.com/mHBona. I want to do a swipe to select hours and duration. 
Using appium inspector-I was able to get only the xpath of hrs and mins and not the entries inside it.
xpath for hrs-//android.view.View[1]
xpath for mins-//android.view.View[2]. I am using webdriver with java.

Answer (score 0):

You could use these two classes.

[org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/touch/TouchActions.html)
[org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.ScrollAction](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/touch/ScrollAction.html)